# SQL Query return if result found else proceed query till end line

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 10 tables in sql and get record from the table where id match with UNION ALL; but my question that where the result found query stop to further process; just like return statement in function in c#

Comment: So you are saying you don't want to execute the remaining queries in the union once you've found 1 result? Suggests Union wasn't teh right choice that.

Comment: yes i don't want to execute the remaining queries !
forget UNION just right choice and good way to do this.

Comment: Looks like the "boys" have provided some alternatives in my abscence, certainly I don't know of a way of breaking out of a sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ... from T1 where ...
if @@RowCount = 0
   select ... from T2 where ...
if @@RowCount = 0
   select ... from T3 where ...
```

If you need to do additional processing on the result, you could either `SELECT INTO` a temporary table or `INSERT`/`SELECT` to a table variable.

**EDIT**: Based on the comment from the OP, may I suggest:

```
declare @Table1 as Table ( Id Int )
declare @Table2 as Table ( Id Int )
declare @Table3 as Table ( Id Int )
declare @Result as Table ( Id Int, Source VarChar(10) )

-- Try changing the following line to use different tables and values.
insert into @Table2 ( Id ) values ( 42 )

insert into @Result
  select Id, 'Table1' from @Table1 where Id = 42
if @@RowCount = 0
  insert into @Result
    select Id, 'Table2' from @Table2 where Id = 42
if @@RowCount = 0
  insert into @Result
    select Id, 'Table3' from @Table3 where Id = 42

select * from @Result
```

Comment: not working; becoz first selection result must come if it is empty then it will show other result, means always display two output first is empty and other is result table if first table have not result.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to continue using UNION ALL is not possible.

Why don't you make a select at a time and check after each select if you've the needed info? If so, end it, if not, continue and do another select.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (exists(select 1 from table1 where condition))
   select col1, col2 from table1 
   where condition
else if(exists(select 1 from table2 where condition))
   select col1, col2 from table2 
   where condition
else if(exists(select 1 from table3 where condition))
   select col1, col2 from table3 
   where condition
... continue until table10
```